# How to keep a set of ant build scripts updated in different java IDEs?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, intellij-idea

My team members are developing different java projects using InteliJ, Eclipse and NetBeans. As a software configuration management practice, I need to have a standard Ant build script for each of these projects. Unfortunately, the ant scripts generated by these IDEs are not in a standard format and may contain many IDE-specific tasks. Furthermore, some IDEs, e.g. InteliJ, do not update the generated Ant files automatically when the project is changed, therefore an automatic build may simply be broken. 
Now, here is the problem: I have a set of build scripts. I need:

1. The scripts to be in a standard format
2. The build scripts to be updated automatically by the used IDEs (InteliJ, Eclipse,NetBeans) when the project is updated.

Is there any straightforward method to do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use IDEs to generate ant scripts.   You need solid repeatable builds working without IDEs (for example on CI server like Hudson/Jenkins).  Best way to have standard build is to use maven, and generate IDE projects from pom.  ( IDEA works with maven natively - no need to 
generate project files )

Comment: Also keep in mind,   that build scripts which are  updated by different IDEs on different machines are hell to merge -  team productivity really suffers from such issues

Comment: And is it possible to convert all of my projects (e.g. .ipr projects) into pom.xml?

Comment: Yep. This is possible,  and as a bonus you will get standart directory layout and  repeatability

Comment: Thanks. May i ask how can i convert my .ipr files into pom.xml?

Comment: You shall not.  Just write proper pom.xml  from scratch ( it is relatively easy,  and poms are formal descriptions and not executable) - IDEA has good support for editing poms, and can open them natively.  Once done, remove iprs  ( and other idea or IDE artifacts)  from version control